# Reemplazar una coma por una coma entre comillas simples en un string

Tags: javascript

En resumidas cuentas los que necesito es sustituir de una cadena los caracteres que sean una coma por una coma entre dos comillas simples.

El resultado que me da no me incluye hasta el momento las comillas simples.

Este es el código JS:

```js
var Cadena = "23,54,N21,98,BIT";
var input = Cadena.trim();

input.replace(",", "\', \'");

var output = input.slice(0, -1);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas, el primero es que el `replace` solo reemplaza la primera ocurrencia. El siguiente problema es que `replace` cambia el valor pero no lo hace sobre la variable que estás usando, así que la tienes que asignar de nuevo.

En resumen, lo que necesitas te quedaría así:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var Cadena = "23,54,N21,98,BIT";
var input = Cadena.trim();

input=input.replaceAll(",", "\', \'");

var output = input.slice(0, -1);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Fernando, tanto por la edición para poder ejecutar el código como por la solución. Cuando me deje te la tickeo como resuelta.

Comment: No hay de que. Estás cosas nos pasan a todos :)

Comment: Este código no funcionaría correctamente si en `search` hubiese caracteres especiales. Todos los caracteres especiales para expresiones regulares deben escaparse.

Comment: En mi caso no me hace falta contemplar caracteres especiales ya que son valores que provienen de un campo ID que está previamente filtrado y que contiene letras, números enteros o combinación de ambos.

Para otro caso que si use caracteres especiales, como dices @Mariano, si puede que falle.